# Use pip to install poetry group dependencies from VCS

Tags: pip, python-poetry

I have a project on VCS / GitHub that is managed using poetry. In that project I use poetry [dependency groups](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/managing-dependencies/#dependency-groups). For example

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]  # main dependency group
httpx = "*"
pendulum = "*"

[tool.poetry.group.server.dependencies]
streamlit = "^1.13.0"
```

Is it possible to `pip install` the GitHub project **and** the dependencies?

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/my/project.git@main#egg=project
```

(for example) will install `httpx` and `pendulum`, but not `streamlit`.

We could move the dependencies from the group into `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` but this defeats the purpose of the poetry group dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

From [reading more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405744/whats-the-difference-between-extras-and-groups-in-poetry), I believe I'm using poetry group dependencies incorrectly (group dependencies should be used during development). What I should be doing is to use `extras` - as in

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]  # main dependency group
httpx = "*"
pendulum = "*"
streamlit = { version = "^1.13.0", optional = true }

[tool.poetry.extras]
server = ["streamlit"]
```

Then we can install the extras with

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/my/project.git@main#egg=project[server]
```